# Place an image next to my title

Tags: html, css

I have a picture and also a picture title. I'm trying to display the text alongside the image. This is my current code

```
 <p class="title">
    <img src="images/football.png" />
    Sports Section
</p>

.title {
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the float from the p tag, and place it on the image.

```
<p class="title">
   <img class="my_image" src="images/football.png" />
   Sports Section
</p>


.my_image {
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the text in the image you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jLFTD/

In your HTML:

```
<p class="title"></p>
```

in your CSS:

```
.title {
background-image: url('http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Ideal-landscape.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: table;
min-width: 100%;
height: 291px;
}

.title:before {
content: "Sports Section";
font-size: 2em;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
color: red;
}
```